# NetBean add library issue

Tags: netbeans-6.9

I am trying to add a folder full of .jar files to netbean project library, but the netbean can not look up classes in the jar files within the folder, I don't want to add each .jar files individually, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the jar files to the library.  You can multi-select the jar files in the add jar to library dialog/file chooser.

[image]